# Strange behavior when modifying tables or procedures in SQL Server 2008 Management Studio

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

This is some weird behavior...

Whenever I script certain tables (using CREATE TO...) or edit stored procedures (using modify in the right click context menu) I sometimes get really weird results... For example, scripting most tables gives me:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo.].[TableINeverAskedFor]
...

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableIWant](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [ModuleID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [OtherInfo] [int] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_ModuleDefinitions] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 

CREATE TABLE [dbo.].[TableINeverAskedFor]
...

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableWhichHasNothingToDoWithMyTable] ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_WhyDoesThisHappen?]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [ID]
```

Stored procedures are even more weird... the bigger the sotred procedure, the more alter scripts I get, just like above.  It's really annoying and I am afraid I'm going to do something stupid and not pay attention one day.

Relevant info:

- I have SQL Server 2008 R2 installed, a new install.
- I have a few developers in my shop experiencing similar problems.
- I also have a SQL Server 2008 box (no R2) doing the same thing.
- My instance is updated with SP1 and theirs aren't.
- We can also replicate the issue on multiple databases.
- Our production server is not giving us the same issue.
- Some stored procedures and tables don't have this problem however the same stored procedures and tables can be replicated.  It's not a random issue.
- I have no plugins installed.

EDIT:  It's not that weird... I can see it being useful for table creation.  Editing a stored procedure though, that was what was very confusing to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Management Studio go to `Tools > Options > SQL Server Object Explorer > Scripting` and change `Generate script for dependent objects` to false. False is the default so you *did* ask for this at some point. ;-)

Comment: awesome, that fixed it but I find it strange that it's working that way for everyone.  You think R2 defaults to that now?  I cant imagine every single one of us decided to change that setting then forget :)

Comment: I looked at a handful of systems that are rarely used interactively and they're all set to false.

Comment: weird... thanks for the info though, I --never-- thought the problem would have been between the chair and keyboard